# Asynchronous single task executor

Tags: java, asynchronous, double-checked-locking

I'm in doubt if the solution below is correct for the following:

- in a multi-user application any user can start processing of given data by clicking a button
- processing takes long time thus it should be executed asynchronously to not block GUI
- if one user has already started the processing, the other requests should be rejected till it completes

Below is the code used to solve this:

```java
    public class Processor {
        private final ExecutorService execService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        private final Object monitor = new Object();
        private AtomicReference<Task> runningTask = new AtomicReference<>(null);
        
        public Optional<CompletableFuture<String>> processDataAsync(String data) {
            if (runningTask.get() != null)
                return Optional.empty();  //rejecting data process request because another request is already being served
            
            synchronized (monitor) {
                if (runningTask.get() != null)
                    return Optional.empty();
                
                CompletableFuture<String> f = new CompletableFuture<>();
                f.whenComplete((r, e) -> runningTask.set(null));  //when processing completes, another data process request can be accepted
                
                Task task = new Task(f, data);
                runningTask.set(task);
                execService.submit(task);
                return Optional.of(f);
            }
        }
    }
```

`Task` is `Runnable` as below:

```java
    public class Task implements Runnable {
        private final CompletableFuture<String> result;
        private final String data;
        
        public Task(CompletableFuture<String> result, String data) {
            this.result = result;
            this.data = data;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String processingResult = processData(data);  //does some blocking stuff with data, returning result of processing
            result.complete(processingResult);
        }
    }
```

What confuses me here is the synchronization (i.e. blocking) in `processDataAsync`. I understand that blocking here is very short and not critical, but shouldn't asynchronous method be always implemented without blocking? If so, I can't imagine how "single processing" can be achieved without synchronization.

Comment: That's not blocking the processing thread and async doesn't ban blocking outright (just strongly discourages it for good reasons). I would've done this with a `ThreadPool` with a zero queuesize and a proper rejectpolicy, but if you want to show off your "skills" with DCL I guess this is a decent effort.

Comment: What exactly do your mean by “multi-user application”? What architecture? Is this a Jakarta EE app?

Comment: It is a web-application based on servlets, running in Tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I’ve misunderstood the problem, but it seems you are over complicating the situation. Rather than keeping track of the task, keep track of the `Future` returned by `ExecutorService#submit`. A `Future` object is your tether leading back to the task being executed.

Define a member field for the `Future`.

```
Future future ;
```

Test the `Future` when request to process is made. Call [`Future#isDone`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone()) to test. Javadoc says:

> Returns true if this task completed. Completion may be due to normal termination, an exception, or cancellation -- in all of these cases, this method will return true.

```
if( Objects.isNull( this.future ) || this.future.isDone() ) {
    … proceed with request to process data.
    this.future = executorService.submit( … ) ;
    return Optional.of( this.future ) ;
} else {
    … Refuse the request to process data.
    … Do *not* submit any task to the executor service. 
    return Optional.empty() ;
}
```

## `TaskMaster` solution

In various comments, you presented more details of your problem.

You want to submit tasks from various threads to a single object. Let's call that object `TaskMaster` for clarity. That `TaskMaster` instance tracks whether its nested executor service is currently working on a task or not.

- If busy working on a task, any incoming task tendered is rejected. That rejection takes the form of an `Optional< Future >`.
- If not currently working on a task, the tendered task is accepted, and assigned to the executor service for immediate execution. This acceptance takes the form of a loaded `Optional< Future >`.

Since the code shown above discussed here will be accessed across threads, we must protect the `Future future ;` in a thread-safe manner. One easy way to do that is to mark `synchronized` on the one and only method for tendering a task to the `TaskMaster`.

```java
package singletask;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

// Runs one task at a time, rejecting any task tendered while already executing a task.
public class TaskMaster
{
    // Member fields.
    private final ExecutorService executorService;
    private Future future;

    // Constructor
    public TaskMaster ( )
    {
        this.executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    public synchronized Optional < Future > tender ( Runnable task )
    {
        if ( Objects.isNull( this.future ) || this.future.isDone() )
        {
            // Proceed with immediate execution of the tendered task.
            this.future = executorService.submit( task );
            return Optional.of( this.future );
        } else
        {
            // Already busy on a task. Reject this tendered task.
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    public void shutdownAndAwaitTerminationOfExecutorService ( )
    {
        if ( Objects.isNull( this.executorService ) ) { return; }
        this.executorService.shutdown(); // Stop new tasks from being submitted.
        try
        {
            // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
            if ( ! this.executorService.awaitTermination( 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) )
            {
                this.executorService.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
                // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
                if ( ! this.executorService.awaitTermination( 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) )
                    System.err.println( "Pool did not terminate." );
            }
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException ex )
        {
            // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
            this.executorService.shutdownNow();
            // Preserve interrupt status
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage shown next. **Beware:** Multithreaded calls to `System.out.println` do *not* always appear on the console chronologically. Always include, and inspect, timestamps to verify the order.

```java
package singletask;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        Runnable task = ( ) -> {
            UUID taskID = UUID.randomUUID();
            System.out.println( "Starting task " + taskID + " at " + Instant.now() );
            // Pretend to do some long hard work, by sleeping.
            try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 5 ).toMillis() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            System.out.println( "Ending task " + taskID + " at " + Instant.now() );
        };

        TaskMaster taskMaster = new TaskMaster();

        Optional < Future > f1 = taskMaster.tender( task ); // We expect acceptance, showing `Optional[java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@…`.
        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofMillis( 500 ).toMillis() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        System.out.println( "f1 = " + f1 );

        Optional < Future > f2 = taskMaster.tender( task ); // We expect rejection, showing `Optional.empty`.
        System.out.println( "f2 = " + f2 );

        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 7 ).toMillis() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        Optional < Future > f3 = taskMaster.tender( task ); // We expect acceptance, showing `Optional[java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@…`.
        System.out.println( "f3 = " + f3 );

        // Attempt a graceful shutwdown.
        taskMaster.shutdownAndAwaitTerminationOfExecutorService();
        System.out.println( "Demo ending at " + Instant.now() );
    }
}
```

When run.

```
Starting task cc48efaa-390b-414d-9f3a-539e2be249b9 at 2022-02-03T06:42:58.516852Z
f1 = Optional[java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@1fb3ebeb[Not completed, task = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@31befd9f[Wrapped task = singletask.App$$Lambda$14/0x0000000800c01208@1c20c684]]]
f2 = Optional.empty
Ending task cc48efaa-390b-414d-9f3a-539e2be249b9 at 2022-02-03T06:43:03.530138Z
Starting task a3de548c-b068-435c-a6cb-856d2f539042 at 2022-02-03T06:43:06.011485Z
f3 = Optional[java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@816f27d[Not completed, task = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@1218025c[Wrapped task = singletask.App$$Lambda$14/0x0000000800c01208@1c20c684]]]
Ending task a3de548c-b068-435c-a6cb-856d2f539042 at 2022-02-03T06:43:11.013576Z
Demo ending at 2022-02-03T06:43:11.014180Z
```

## Custom `ExecutorService`

While that `TaskMaster` code above works, and offers the `Optional` objects you asked for, I would recommend another approach.

You can make your own version of an `ExecutorService`. Your implementation could do something similar to what we saw above, tracking a single task’s execution.

Rather than returning an `Optional< Future >`, the more orthodox approach would be to provide a [`submit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)) method implementation that either:

- Returns a `Future` if the tendered task can be immediately executed, or …
- Throws a [`RejectedExecutionException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionException.html) because a task is already running.

This behavior is defined in the Javadoc of `ExecutorService`. Any methods of your which tender tasks to this custom executor service would trap for this exception rather than examine an `Optional`.

In other words, to modify an excerpt from your Comment:

> If two users simultaneously try to request data processing, only one of them will succeed and receive a `Future`, and another will see an exception thrown, indicating that the request was rejected.

With this custom executor service, the calling programmer has less to learn. The calling programmer would not need to understand the semantics of the `TaskMaster` class, they need to understand only the common `ExecutorService` behavior.

Tip: The [`AbstractExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html) class might make creating your own executor service easier.

Comment: This is not thread-safe. The fact that multiple users can simultaneously trigger heavy data processing forced me to use synchronization to prevent this. But may be there is a concurrency feature that can do the same without synchronization. Of I'm just too worried about async method blocked for short time.

Comment: @Bobby_Bob (a) Having to wait for one task to finish is not a thread safety issue. I suggest you read [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) to understand the technical term.

Comment: @Bobby_Bob (b) Your Comment is confusing, contradicting your Question. You asked how to refuse a second task submission if a task is currently being executed. That is what my Answer provides. There would be no “multiple users” to “trigger heavy data processing”. There would be exactly zero or one task ever executing. Furthermore, the single threaded executor in both your code and mine would ensure no multiple executions.

Comment: Thank you for comments. Let me explain. With my code, if two users simultaneously try to request data processing, only one of them will succeed, and another will get Optional.empty(), indicating that the request was rejected. With your code, both users will get Future to obtain data processing result, because both requests will be submitted to ExecutorService and executed one by one. This is what I need to avoid.

Comment: @Bobby_Bob So return either an empty `Optional` or a loaded `Optional`, in either branch of my `if` test. See my edits.

Comment: Sorry for being not clear in problem statement. Yes, the same instance of `Processor` is accessed by multiple threads. I don't get how wrapping `future` with `Optional` can help because multiple threads still can have `if( Objects.isNull( this.future ) || this.future.isDone() )` as `true` if they get here simultaneously. It looks like there is no concurrency "trick" that may help to avoid synchronization. And I start thinking it is not bad in this case.

Comment: @Bobby_Bob Given your additional details, I revamped my Answer. See my `TaskMaster` example code. And see my suggestion to write your own custom `ExecutorService` implementation.

Comment: thank you for suggestions. Yes, this will solve the task if there is a way for custom `ExecutorService` to awoid sinchronization while accepting/rejecting a task. That is what I can't find so far.

Comment: @Bobby_Bob What is your concern about synchronization? My `tender` method is `synchronized` but takes only a brief moment to execute. Performing a null-check, calling `Future#isDone` & `ExecutorService#submit`, and forming an `Optional`, are all very fast, not a bottleneck. The locks for synchronized are optimized in modern JVMs.

Comment: I think you are right. My concern is about locking the method call that is meant to be asynchronous, but since synchronized block execution is short and never depends on duration of executed task, the solution is good.